# Indesign Script to Apply "Object Style" to Specific XML Structure Tags

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

Is there a way to come up with a javascript within InDesign that after importing images via XML into InDesign, I can run a script that will map a specific object style to a particular tag? Just like the Tags allow when it comes with Paragraph styles and Character styles. Do not know why Adobe did not allow object styles to work the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer as follows ...

```
/**
IMAGE OBJECT STYLE SCRIPT
 */

var actions = [

   /*
   -------------------------
   | ACTION:Default Action |
   -------------------------
   */

function DefaultAction(){

    /** command array */
    var commands = [

    /** ACTION FUNCTIONS BEGIN HERE: **/

        /* Assign a property from the objectStyles collection */
        function assign_appliedObjectStyle(obj){ 
            obj.appliedObjectStyle = document.objectStyles.itemByName("Image"); 
        }

    ];

    /** START ACTION EXECUTION CODE: **/

    var applyToSelection = [true,true,true,true];
    var repeats = 1;
    while(repeats--){
    for(var idx=0; idx < commands.length; idx++){
        try{var i = void 0; (!applyToSelection[idx])?commands[idx]():(function(command){
        while((i = (i||0)+1) <= app.selection.length){
             try{ command(app.selection[i-1]); }catch(err){
                //Selection command error handling code here.
             }
        }})(commands[idx]);}catch(err){
            //Insert Error Handling Code Here.
    }}}

 /** END ACTION EXECUTION CODE: **/

}
];
for(var idx = 0; idx < actions.length; idx++){
         actions[idx]()                       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found somewhat same question posted on Adobe forums ..
Following is the link for it..

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/740264

Hope this Helps..

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I was hoping that it could be done without external script involved. But that may end up being the only answer. Still going to hold out and see. It may require me to dig deeper and come up with my own if possible. If I do, I will post it.